# Functions in scikit that detect outliers automatically?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, anomaly-detection, outlier

I know a way to visualize outliers is to make a box plot, but wanted to know if scikit had any quick ways to detect outliers for each variable?

Comment: Do you want a univariate approach, or multivariate?

Comment: @jonnor univariate is fine

Answer (score 2):

The scikit-learn implementations of Isolation Forest and Local Outlier Factor should help you out here. Details on both at this link:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html